# How to get all iteams that matches the item being searched for

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, while-loop, c-strings

Function:

```
    Option2(char Firstname[][20],char search[],int size)
     {
         int i;
         for(i=0;i<=size;i++)
         {
             if(strcmp(Firstname[i],search)==0)
             {
                 return i;
             }
         }
         return -1;
     }
```

> The function is supposed to compare search to each item on the array and return all items that match search

main:

```
    case 2:
                printf("\nEnter a first name to search: ");
                scanf("%s",Nsearch);
                temp = Option2(Firstname,Nsearch,size);
                if(temp!=-1)
                {
                    printf("First Name:%s Last Name:%s Score: %.2f\n",Firstname[temp],Lastname[temp],score[temp]);
                }
                break;
```

> How can I print out all the items that match search and not just the first item that match search?

Comment: In C really try and steer away from function signatures like `char Firstname[][20]` and instead have `char** firstname`. Don't put arbitrary limits on sizes, nor make wild assumptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters it seems in the function there is a bug in the loop condition

```
for(i=0;i<=size;i++)
```

it should be

```
for(i=0; i < size;i++)
```

You can call the function in loop like

```
temp = 0;
int i = 0'
while ( ( temp = Option2(Firstname + i,Nsearch, size - i) ) != - 1 )
{
    i += temp;
    printf("First Name:%s Last Name:%s Score: %.2f\n",Firstname[i],Lastname[i],score[i]);
    ++i;
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how loops can be used to output elements found in the array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N   20

int Option2( char Firstname[][N], char search[], int size )
{
    int i = 0;

    while ( i < size && strcmp( Firstname[i], search ) != 0 ) i++;

    return i == size ? -1 : i;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char names[][N] = { "chanu", "bob", "chanu" };
    const int M = ( int )( sizeof( names ) / sizeof( *names ) );
    char s[] =  "chanu";

    int i = 0, j = 0;

    while ( ( j = Option2( names + i, s, M - i ) ) != -1 )
    {
        i += j;

        printf( "%d: \"%s\"\n", i, names[i] );

        ++i;
    }

    putchar( '\n' );

    for ( int i = 0, j = 0; ( j = Option2( names + i, s, M - i ) ) != -1; i++ )
    {
        i += j;

        printf( "%d: \"%s\"\n", i, names[i] );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
0: "chanu"
2: "chanu"

0: "chanu"
2: "chanu
```

Comment: @AndreasWenzel It was a typo.

Comment: @ AndreasWenzel Thank you so much!

Comment: @chanu: It was not me who answered the question, I just made a comment pointing out an error in the answer. Meanwhile, I have deleted my comment, because the answerer has fixed the error.

Answer (score 1):

As the function returns the index of the first match, use that to adjust subsequent searches

```
    printf("\nEnter a first name to search: ");
    scanf("%s",Nsearch);

    int offset = 0;
    while (size > offset && (temp = Option2(Firstname+offset, Nsearch, size-offset) != -1)) {
      printf("First Name:%s Last Name:%s Score: %.2f\n", 
          Firstname[offset+temp], Lastname[offset+temp], score[offset+temp]);
      offset += temp + 1;
    }
    break;
```